# can i get last 3 data from database record?

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, eloquent, laravel-8

I have 6 data in database record but I want to get last 3 data

this is my data :

| criteria_id | criteria_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |
| 6 | F |

i have tried with this code :

```
 $criteria= criteria::latest()->take(3)->get();
```

but i got data like this :

| criteria_id | criteria_name |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | F |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

and I also tried with orderby the result is like this :

| criteria_id | criteria_name |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | F |
| 5 | E |
| 4 | D |

the result should be like this, i want this result :

| criteria_id | criteria_name |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |
| 6 | F |

how can i get data like last result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your row would need a `created_at` column to use `latest()`, but what you have would work. Alternatively, you could sort on the `criteria_id` column, then take 3.

```
Criteria::orderBy('criteria_id', 'desc')->take(3)->get();
```

Edit: Just saw your changes. Just do the above then add a sortBy on the collection

```
Criteria::orderBy('criteria_id', 'desc')->take(3)->get()->sortBy('criteria_id');
```

Comment: Did you see my revised answer? If you can get the 3 records you want, then you can change the sort however you want using the collection `sortBy` or `sortByDesc` methods.

Comment: `->latest('criteria_id')` would [work](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L2251-L2260) too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of latest() make a sortition in a descending order and simply take as many as you need.